# Angular post data is not going to Django REST API

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, angular6

I'm using `Angular 6` and `Django REST Framework`

The view of DRF is

```
class AmountGivenViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AmountGivenSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return AmountGiven.objects.filter(
            contact__user=self.request.user
        )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        save_data = {}

        print(self.request.POST)
        # validate user and to save_data dictionary
        contact_pk = self.request.POST.get('contact', None)
        print(contact_pk)
        if not contact_pk:
            raise ValidationError({'contact': ['Contact is required']})

        contact = Contact.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user,
            pk=contact_pk
        ).first()

        if not contact:
            raise ValidationError({'contact': ['Contact does not exists']})

        # add contact to save_data dictionary
        save_data['contact'] = contact

        # process mode_of_payment is in request
        mode_of_payment_pk = self.request.POST.get('mode_of_payment', None)

        if mode_of_payment_pk:
            mode_of_payment = ModeOfPayment.objects.get(pk=mode_of_payment_pk)
            if not mode_of_payment:
                raise ValidationError({'mode_of_payment': ['Not a valid mode of payment']})

            # add mode_of_payment to save_data dictionary
            save_data['mode_of_payment'] = mode_of_payment

        # pass save_data dictionary to save()
        serializer.save(**save_data)
```

**AmountGivenSerializer** in **serializers.py**

```
class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AmountGiven
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 'contact', 'amount', 'interest_rate', 'duration', 'given_date', 'promised_return_date',
            'mode_of_payment', 'transaction_number', 'interest_to_pay', 'total_payable', 'amount_due',
            'total_returned', 'comment', 'modified', 'created'
        )
```

and in **Angular component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {AmountGiven} from '../amount-given.model';
import {AmountGivenService} from '../amount-given.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-amount-given-add',
  templateUrl: './amount-given-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./amount-given-add.component.css']
})
export class AmountGivenAddComponent implements OnInit {

  addMoneyForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  contact_id: string;

  amountGiven: AmountGiven;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private amountGivenService: AmountGivenService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.params.subscribe(
      param => {
        this.contact_id = param['contact_id'];
      }
    );

    this.addMoneyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      amount: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      interest_rate: new FormControl(),
      duration: new FormControl(),
      given_date: new FormControl(),
      promised_return_date: new FormControl(),
      transaction_number: new FormControl(),
      mode_of_payment: new FormControl(),
      comment: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  get f() {
    return this.addMoneyForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.addMoneyForm.invalid) {
      console.log('invalid');
      return;
    }

    const data = this.addMoneyForm.value;
    data.contact = this.contact_id;

    this.amountGivenService.add(data).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('req completed', res);
    });
  }

}
```

But when form is submited it returns validation error from server for **contact** field.

```
{"contact":["Contact is required"]}
```

The request header has the **contact** parameter

[image]

sending the same request from **Postman** is working fine. The **Javascript XHR** code of Postman request is

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("amount", "5000");
data.append("contact", "65827a1f-003e-4bb3-8a90-6c4321c533e6");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://koober-production.herokuapp.com/api/amount-given/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ATjIuQ6hLzc55wHaXIzHmcKafEzk1B");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "28d9d33a-f0a6-431c-8936-da4f6565ece4");

xhr.send(data);
```

could not understand this issue is related to **Angular** or **Django** because Postman request is working fine with **Djano** and Angular is sending the request in the parameter.

> Edit 2: **AmountGivenService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ResourceProviderService} from '../../resource-provider.service';
import {AuthService} from '../../auth/auth.service';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {AmountGiven} from './amount-given.model';
import {AppHttpClient} from '../../app-http-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AmountGivenService {

  private url = 'amount-given/';

  constructor(
    private http: AppHttpClient
  ) { }

  add(data): Observable<AmountGiven> {

    return this.http.Post<AmountGiven>(this.url, data);
  }

}
```

which is furhter using **AppHttpClient**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ResourceProviderService} from './resource-provider.service';

export interface IRequestOptions {
  headers?: HttpHeaders;
  observe?: 'body';
  params?: HttpParams;
  reportProgress?: boolean;
  responseType?: 'json';
  withCredentials?: boolean;
  body?: any;
}

export function appHttpClientCreator(http: HttpClient, resource: ResourceProviderService) {
  return new AppHttpClient(http, resource);
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AppHttpClient {

  private api_url = this.resource.url + '/api/';

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    private resource: ResourceProviderService
  ) {
  }

  public Post<T>(endPoint: string, params: Object, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(this.api_url + endPoint, params, options)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('post', endPoint, null))
      );
  }

  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', endpoint = '', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      console.log(error.message);
      console.log(operation);
      console.log(endpoint);

      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the `AmountGivenService`?

Comment: Hi Anuj, you may need to add the following to your form element (I'm not sure on the Angular way of doing this), but I know Django expects `x-www-form-urlencoded`, so depending on how Angular handles this you'll need somethign that replicates: `<form method="POST" action="url/to/your-DRF-endpoint" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">`

Comment: @R.Richards update question with requested code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access:

```
self.request.POST.get('contact', None)
```

in DRF you need to do:

```
self.request.data.get('contact', None)
```

It works from postman because you're constructing a FormData object which is fundamentally different from the JSON body angular will send and that is expected by a RESTful API like DRF.

from a more general standpoint, in DRF, serializers should perform the request validation using the built in validators, rather than manually validating in the view.

Comment: While connecting android through retrofit to drf `request.POST` works fine but why it's not working with angular why have we have to use `request.data` instead ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm hesitant to add this as the answer just yet, but it feels like you need to add something along the lines of:

```
<form method="POST" action="url/to/your-DRF-endpoint" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
 ....
</form>
```

Either within your template or within your Angular POST request code you need to make sure the data is posted as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Essentially, Django expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and without it your `self.request.POST` object will be empty and hence `self.request.POST.get('contact', None)` will be empty and default to `None`.

Comment: Django expects a standard form, DRF expects a JSON body as angular will send, the issue is how he's attempting to access the data in the view.